# Pagination on a underscore custom theme

Tags: loop, pagination, blog

I am trying to add a pagination feature on my blog page. The loop outputs the post grid fine but the pagination does not work and the Wordpress documentation does not work. I have no idea what going wrong.

```
<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>6)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>


<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php  if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) : ?>
<div class="grid__item desk-one-third pb-20">
    <figure class="snip1206">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        <figcaption>
            <h2>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <p>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </p>
        </figcaption>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </figure>
</div>
<!--

-->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="grid__item desk-one-third pb-20">
    <figure class="snip1206">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        <figcaption>
            <h2>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <p>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </p>
        </figcaption>
        <a href=" <?php the_permalink(); ?> "></a>
    </figure>
</div>
<!--

-->

<?php endif ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries' );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>

    <!-- Add the pagination functions here. -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <p>
        <?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing a secondary query with `$wpb_all_query`? Pagination is designed to work with the main query. Since your custom query is essentially just the main query for the posts page, I don't see why you need to do it at all?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I created the if statement to make sure that there are posts in the first place.

Comment: Eh? That's not what I'm talking about. Why did you create `$wpb_all_query` with a `new WP_Query()`?

Comment: The "endif" right above your navigation code is missing the semicolon.